# Wysiwyg editor for webform 5

Tags: webforms, wysiwyg

Is there a way to configure textarea fields in Webform 5 to use Wysiwyg editor ? preferably without coding and overlay capability (I mean something like https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Textarea-Fullscreen-Mode.html) ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch the Webform's HTML Editor to any 'Text format' which are fully customizable.

@see /admin/structure/webform/config/elements

[image]